# can I pass __construct parameters after a class has been instantiated into an object?

Tags: php, oop

I have a similar code snippet like this

```
class Search
{
    public function search($for, $regEx, $flag) //I would like this to be the constructor
    {
        // logic here
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that creates an object from it, later than tries to use the object.

```
class MyClass
{
    public function start()
    {
        $this->search = new Search();
    }

    public function load()
    {
        $this->search($for, $regEx, $flag);
    }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to create an object first THEN give it the parameters?

I know there are some way around this BUT I only ask because I want to use the object like this

```
$this->search($params);
// I have my methods chained, so I could use it in one line like
// $this->search($params)->hasResults();

if ($this->search->hasResults()) {
    echo 'found stuff';
} else {
    echo 'didn't find anything';
}
```

The way I have it set up right now, I would need to use it like this

```
$this->search->search($params);

if ($this->search->hasResults()) {
    echo 'found stuff';
} else {
    echo 'didn't find anything';
}
```

I have a method called `search()` that does the logic, and I don't want to be redundant in my naming nor do I want to change the name of the method.

I know another way to keep the visual appeal sane I could pass a variable like so

`$search = $this->search->search($params);`

then

`$search->hasResults();`

At the same time I am trying to introduce myself to new OOP concepts and learn from them. Would this require passing things by reference? or setting up some type of magic method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the previous anwsers show that you can, I wouldn't use it, because it breaks the concept of encapsulation. A proper way to achieve what you want is the following

```
class Search
{
  public function __constructor($for='', $regEx='', $flag='')
  {
      $this->Setup($for, $regEx, $flag);
  }

   public function Setup($for, $regEx, $flag)
    {
        //assign params
        //clear last result search

        //chain
        return $this;
    }

 public function search()
 {
    // logic here
    return $this;
 }
}
```

In this way, you can reuse the object and have the params in the constructor, without breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can.

```
class Example {
  public $any;
  function __counstruct($parameters,$some_text) {
     $this->any=$some_text;
     return $this->any;
  }
}
```

You can call constructor:

```
$obj = new Example (true,'hello');
echo $obj->any;
$obj->__construct(true,'bye-bye');
echo $obj->any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

See the below example

```
<?php
class a{
    public $a = 5;

    public function __construct($var){
        $this->a = $var;
    }
}

$delta = new a(10);
echo $delta->a."\n";
$delta->__construct(15);
echo $delta->a."\n";
```

Output will be:

```
10 15
```

Comment: execute the above code and check. it works in 5.3.x version of php

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the visual coding I wanted by using the `__call()` magic method like this

```
public function __call($name, $params)
{
    $call = ucfirst($name);
    $this->$name = new $call($params);
}
```

from there I could use this

```
$this->test->search($params);
$this->test->search->hasResults();
```

I of course now set the `search()` method to the class constructor